# Need to make calendar events with no using java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, events, calendar

I have a task to make a code to print calendar like at the photo below:

[image]

User has to enter the month and year.Code bellow shows what I need, but only to add methods to add events and show events. I don't know where and how to start with it? I think the best idea is to save the data to some file or something.

```
public static int day(int M, int D, int Y) {
    int y = Y - (14 - M) / 12;
    int x = y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
    int m = M + 12 * ((14 - M) / 12) - 2;
    int d = (D + x + (31*m)/12) % 7;
    return d;
}

// return true if the given year is a leap year
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if  ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) return true;
    if  (year % 400 == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ulaz = new Scanner(System.in);
    int M = ulaz.nextInt();    // month (Jan = 1, Dec = 12)
    int Y = ulaz.nextInt();    // year

    // months[i] = name of month i
    String[] months = {
        "",                               // leave empty so that months[1] = "January"
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December"
    };

    // days[i] = number of days in month i
    int[] days = {
        0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
    };

    // check for leap year
    if (M == 2 && isLeapYear(Y)) days[M] = 29;


    // print calendar header
    System.out.println("   " + months[M] + " " + Y);
    System.out.println(" S  M Tu  W Th  F  S");

    // starting day
    int d = day(M, 1, Y);

    // print the calendar
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        System.out.print("   ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= days[M]; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
        if (((i + d) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[M])) System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: *Why* can't you use `java.util.Calendar`? And can you use other APIs such as Joda Time or `java.time`? It's very unclear what you're asking at the moment.

Comment: @Jon Skeet My teacher wants it that way, no use java.util.Calendar ... but if someone can make it using java.util.Calendar I'd like to see  how does it work too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a nice tutorial about how to make a calendar from scratch,including events display. It is in french but the full code is available in comments: http://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/php/calendrier-php-157

Regarding your matter, the best is to store your events in a database.
Basically you should create a table with colums as follow:
id_event, date_event, time_event, description_event .... and other details if you need.

You would then query the database via a php script (see php pdo tutorials). And ultimately you could add, store, modify events via javascript and ajax calls to the php script. I personally use jQuery for that via the function getJSON.

Good luck :)